# Break from array and run another function in python

Tags: python, python-2.x

My code:

```
def exit():
   return "Exit" 

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

def func():
   for element in arr:
      print element
```

I want to run `exit()` after every 3 elements of the array and then resume from the last element.

Comment: What do you want to do with the return value of `exit()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and modulo:

```
def exit():
    return "Exit"


arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

def func():
    for ind, element in enumerate(arr, 1):
        print element
        if ind % 3 == 0:
            print(exit())
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
Exit
4
5
6
Exit
7
8
9
Exit
0
```

If you actually want to use `n` elements at a time maybe passing them to a function:

```
from itertools import islice

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

def func():
    it = iter(arr)
    for sli in iter(lambda: list(islice(it, 3)),[]):
        print(sli) # pass sli to function
        print(exit())

func()
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
Exit
[4, 5, 6]
Exit
[7, 8, 9]
Exit
[0]
Exit
```

Comment: I am using python 2.x, can I use this code in python 2.x too?

Comment: @Sanidhay, you can use it in python2 or pyrhon3

Comment: What is *pyrhon3*?  .... Also [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: @BhargavRao, you are slipping ;)

Comment: Lol, nope... *Each time you nake a typo, the errorists win*

Comment: @BhargavRao, pyrhon3 is closely related to python3 ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
def func():
   for i, element in enumerate(arr, 1):
      print element
      if not i%3:
          print(exit())
```

However, I question some parts of your code. Here are some notes:
`arr` is a python list, not an array, so the name is not the best one.
Your `exit` function simply returns the string "Exit", are you sure it does what it is supposed to do? I am printing the return value of `exit()`, because simply calling it would do nothing useful. In addition, it would probably be better to write `func` such that it takes a list as a parameter. Lastly, `exit` is already a built-in Python function, overriding it is a bad idea.